# セルが空白のときに起きるエラーの回避方法(TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len())

Tags: python, python3

■やりたいこと
1.Big queryで2つテーブルを作成（tableA,tableBとします）
2.この2つのテーブルnameを比較して一致率が高い文字列を横並びでCSVで抽出

→ここまではできている

tableA

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 美容院A |
| 2 | 美容院B |
| 3 | 美容院C |

tableB

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 美容院b |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | 美容院A 渋谷店 |

■問題点
上記のようにテーブルBに空白がある場合、下記のようなエラーがでてしまい処理が途中でとまってしまう
`TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

■試したこと
以下が全体のコードになります。
`if len(result) <= 0:`以下の部分でtry,exceptで空白の場合は無視するようにしたつもりなのですがそれでも同じエラーがでてしまいます。

このような場合はどうやって例外処理を無視してスクリプトが動くようにすればよいでしょうか。

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import db_dtypes
import pandas as pd
from difflib import get_close_matches, SequenceMatcher
import csv

client = bigquery.Client()

string01 = """
SELECT name from `tableA`
"""
## Make an API request(?)
string_01 = client.query(string01)

## Dataframeに格納
df_string01 = client.query(string01).to_dataframe()
## listに変換
list_string01 = df_string01['name'].to_list()
print(list_string01)


string02 = """
SELECT name from `tableB`
"""
# Make an API request(?)
stirng_02 = client.query(string02)

## Dataframeに格納
df_string02 = client.query(string02).to_dataframe()
## listに変換
list_string02 = df_string02['name'].to_list()
print(list_string02)


## リストのname列を比較して類似度を出す
# https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90287/python-difflib%e3%81%a72%e3%81%a4%e3%81%ae%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e5%86%85%e3%81%ab%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e6%96%87%e5%ad%97%e5%88%97%e3%82%92%e6%af%94%e8%bc%83%e3%81%97-%e9%a1%9e%e4%bc%bc%e5%ba%a6%e3%81%8c%e6%9c%80%e3%82%82%e9%ab%98%e3%81%84%e6%96%87%e5%ad%97%e5%88%97%e3%82%92%e6%a8%aa%e4%b8%a6%e3%81%b3%e3%81%a7csv%e3%81%a7%e5%87%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84/90294#90294

## リスト b から一番類似している文字列を抽出し→類似度を取得しリストとして返す関数を定義

def closest(x):
    result = get_close_matches(x,list_string02,n=1,cutoff=0.5)
    ### resultが0の場合(似ている文字列がない場合)返り値を「0.0」として返す処理
    if len(result) <= 0:
        try:
            return[x, None, 0.0]
        except:
            pass  
    result = result[0] 
    s = SequenceMatcher(None, x, result) #xとresultの一致率を抽出
    return [x, result, s.ratio()] #返り値を表示(一致率)

## list_string01のデータ全てを順番に処理するリスト内包表記
data = [closest(s) for s in list_string01]

## csvファイルとして出力
## open_csv.py
with open('close.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    csvwriter.writerow(['string01','string02','類似度'])
    csvwriter.writerows(data)
```

Comment: まずエラーが発生している場合, メッセージ内容を省略することなく記してください (どの箇所でエラーが発生しているのか出てるはず)。
あと, 設計に関する質問でない ＆ BigQuery のエラーじゃないなら, BigQueryは外して質問した方が回答 付きやすいかも (「実際は BigQueryで処理してます」の一言あれば済む話)

Comment: 実際にはどのように行いたいか質問に記したほうがよいでしょう。単純に `None`無視するなら, `result = get_close_matches(x,[s for s in list_string02 if s is not None],n=1,cutoff=0.5)` などに変更すれば OK, のはず

Comment: 加えて、if result is not None:を先頭に入れたほうが良いですね